# Number of elements in a set

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb F$ be a field with $8$ elements and $$A=\{x \in \mathbb F:x^7=1 \text{ and } x^k\neq 1 \text{ for all natural numbers } k< 7\}.$$ Then what is the number of elements in $A$?

Comment: Hint: $A - \{0\}$ is a multaplicative group with seven elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually $A$ is the subset of elements of order $7$ in $\mathbb F_8^{\times}$ and you are asking for how many elements of order $7$ has this group. But a cyclic group of order $7$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_7$, and now I leave you the pleasure to find out how many elements of order $7$ are in $\mathbb Z_7$.